# UX interview support and call center representatives

Tags: research

I'm working on an existing e commerce fashion website. before jumping into conclusions I thought it would be best to interview call center and customer support representatives.
I know it is a very common method in UX research yet I couldn't find any guide questionnaire or best practise for what to research.
Any ideas or references .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but what you would research really gets down to which users you're working on in terms of *user experience*. While many do assume that one size fits all, it most definitely doesn't.

For example, are you working on the user experience of the website's users? Or the experience of existing customers when they seek support? Something else? All of the above?

Also, if by *interview* you mean a survey, these are often difficult to pull together and often aren't the best way to start. Sure, with today's tools you can create one relatively quickly, but knowing what questions to ask and how to minimise bias is the hard part. And, depending on the number of responses you get and how you collect them, *may* also be extremely time consuming.

I guess what I'm saying is that a survey may be the way to go, but this depends on what you're trying to achieve. UX surveys are typically good for things like:

- understanding why users actually visited your website
- getting feedback from users on a new feature, product or service
- gathering *quantitative* data on customer satisfaction
- gathering *quantitative* data to back up your qualitative research

If, on the other hand, you're not talking about a survey per se, but instead you're trying to do some qualitative research by conducting interviews, then you wouldn't necessarily have a set questionnaire. Yes, you may have a general guide, but the best *interviews* are those that are fairly open-ended and allow users to speak freely about things. And, better still, the feedback/responses you get help to guide your follow-up questions and what you end up asking subsequent users. This is the best way to discover your users' needs, motivations, frustrations, fears and *how* they use your product or service!

Once you've done this, you *could* then investigate the possibility of a survey to gather the *quantitative* data to back up your findings from the interviews (i.e. your qualitative research).

In summary, your questionnaire and *what to research* will really get down to your specific environment (i.e. users, organisation, industry, etc).

**Further reading**

Below are some references for further reading:

- [Best Practices for Qualitative User Research](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/best-practices-for-qualitative-user-research)
- [When to Use Which User-Experience Research Methods](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/which-ux-research-methods/)
- [Quantitative vs. Qualitative Usability Testing](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/quant-vs-qual/)
- [12 UX Research Techniques (Quantitative and Qualitative)](https://medium.com/ux-design-web-mobile-virtual-reality/12-ux-research-techniques-quantitative-and-qualitative-1a37bcb1914e)
- [Complete Beginner’s Guide to UX Research](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/complete-beginners-guide-to-design-research/)
- [Product Manager’s Guide To UX Research](https://uxstudioteam.com/ux-blog/ux-research/)
- [UX survey: Do you really need a UX survey? And how to do it?](https://uxstudioteam.com/ux-blog/ux-survey/)

Comment: Extremely helpful I'll hang on to it. In addition to user research.To understand the product's life cycle and overall service experience I find it important to receive some data from the support team such as main friction points and logistics limitations, known issues etc. this data might be valuable when addressing "messaging" and clarification issues and surely helps with building the website's "help center". I'm looking for a proper method to address this. based on your comment , qualitative research methods such as open interview might serve me better. to gather some background .